# R: Reticulate -- How to call a Python script that requires multiple command line arguments

Tags: r, reticulate

I have a script called `DataRetrieval.py`.  This script connects to an internal database, retrieves data and writes that data to an Excel file.  This script imports the following:

a) a `utils.py` helper module that contains several functions

b) a `DataRetrieval.cfg` **configuration file** (which contains all of the login information and SQL queries that the `DataRetrieval.py` script needs)

The `DataRetrieval.py` script takes the following 3 command line arguments:

```
DataRetrieval.py   DataRetrieval.cfg   03/01/20
```

(the script itself, the configuration file, and a start date)

I would like to use the `Reticulate` package in R to:

1. call each of these 3 command line arguments
2. set the output of the script (which is an Excel file) to an object (the end goal is to call this object in a Shiny dashboard)

I was thinking about using the `source_python()` function, but I don't think it allows for multiple positional arguments.  The error message returns:

```
> source_python("DataRetrieval.py")
Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : SystemExit: 2
usage: python.exe [-h] [-e ENDDATE] config startDate
python.exe: error: the following arguments are required: config, startDate
```

What is the best way to use the `Reticulate` package to call these 3 command line arguments?  Perhaps a single `.py` file that encapsulates each of the 3 arguments above?

Thanks!

Comment: Why use `reticulate` and not a command line call with `system()` especially if you do not need any Python objects in R environment?

Comment: The end goal is to use Shiny.  Our internal API is not exposed to R.  Therefore, the use of Reticulate.  How does one use system() in that setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**  I solved this problem by creating a .py file named `retrieve.py` and passing that file to the `source_python()` Reticulate function.  The `retrieve.py` file reads as follows:

```
import os

os.system('python DataRetrieval.py DataRetrieval.cfg 02/01/20')
```